# Unknown column in field list for a query with two tables

Tags: php, mysql

Maybe I'm having a brain fart but this query:

```
$query = "select project.id as projectid, participants.member_id from project";
```

gives me the error "unknown column 'participants.member_id'in 'field list' "

even though the table "project" has a column called id and the table participants has a column called member_id.
I want to eventually inner join them, but can't even get past the above simple query,  Am I missing something?

BTW: the line above (not shown) successfully connects to the database that contains these two tables.  And both of these tables are in the same database).

Comment: You don't mention the `participants` table in the query - you're just selecting from `project`

Comment: doesn't participants.member_id refer to the participants table?

Comment: without joining you cant select this way.

Comment: @user2557039 It does, but you're only selecting from `project` so your query can't find it.

Comment: you have to have cross reference to join the tables. Like 

"select project.id as projectid, participants.member_id from project, participants where participants.projectId = project.id"

Answer (score 1):

As @MikeW mentioned, you don't have `participants` in the query (each query is independent of each other).

You may want to do a `LEFT JOIN` to collect the results you want.

```
$query = "SELECT project.id AS projectid, participants.member_id FROM project LEFT JOIN participants ON participants.project_id = project.id";
```

If you have a common key **participants.project_id** and **project.id** between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the participants table to the equation -

```
$query = "select project.id as projectid, participants.member_id from project, participants";
```